# unity: lighting in right eye cardboard sdk

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

I am using Cardboard VR SDK version 2 for unity 5.6.2p1 and the lights is not working on the right eye

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem can occur if you're using Real Time Lightning, make sure that you're using Baked Light. 
Here's some useful video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sSSl-YGAiFA